# Add ical feed to native calendar in Ionic

Tags: ionic-framework, calendar, icalendar

We develop a ionic 3 app for iOS and Android based on a series on events. All events are stored on the server. Several clients can create, edit and delete events. All clients subscribe to these events.

Some of our customers would like to add these events to the native calendar.
We currently have a ical-feed which they can add to their google calendar as "a seperate calendar" and then the google calendar will automatically sync these events.
This is nice but not very userfriendly to setup.
It is also hard to do on iOS.
We whould like the user to subscribe to his events through the app. Not one single event but the entire list of upcomming events.

The ionic native calendar plugin lets us create events from the app which is nice but with the methods available there would be a lot of work to be done to be able to sync events with native calendar every time the app fetches event updates.

The list of events can contain new events, changed events and also if a event is deleted the updated list will no longer contain the deleted event. Also all properties of an event could change so to be able to determine a event, we need to use the event ID (which comes with the event list from the server).

The events displayed in the native calendar is mostly for display. Changing events is done in the app or on a web interface (server).
This means that the native calendar sync can sync one-way: app->calendar
How would you recommend us solving this issue from the ionic app?